# Passive Attenuator + Level shift simulation slightly off from hand calculations not sure where mistake is

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice, voltage-divider, level-shifting

I am trying to take a +/- 3.5V signal and shift it into the 0.65V to 2.65V range for input into an ADC with common mode of 1.65V. I have calculated the attached circuit by hand but when I simulate it on LT Spice I am just slightly off. I also have the constraint that R1 = 50 ohm in the circuit. [image]

At -3.5V I want an output of .65V but I am getting about .5V. At +3.5V I want an output of 2.65V but I am getting only 2.05V. This is my first time simulating on LT Spice so I am not sure if my calculations are wrong or maybe it is my simulation.
Here is simulation at 3.5V
[image]

And this is simulation at -3.5V
[image]

Comment: Contrary to the opinion expressed in the answer you accepted, your requirements *can* be met with the relatively simple voltage-divider type circuit you're trying to use. Change the pull-down resistor (R4 in your sketch, R2 in your LT Spice schematic) to a value of 66.8 ohms.

Comment: Oh wow thank you that did work. May I ask where in my calculations I went wrong and how you came up with 66.8ohms for that resistor?

Comment: I agreed with your 1st step of finding the thevenin equivalent for the voltage divider and getting 14.3. But when 'deconstructing' Rth back to the 2 individual resistors I applied superposition to the 50R input resistance and the input voltage source. The voltage source becomes a short circuit, putting the input resistor in parallel with the lower leg of the divider. So from there calculated the lower leg's resistance to result in 28.6R as 66.8R with the 50R in parallel with it. I think carloc's answer probably ends up going in the same direction (although it looks incomplete).

Comment: Ok that makes sense and clears it up for me. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just wrong with voltage dividers, twice .

In the beginning, if you have to map 7V peak to peak onto 2V you need a 1/3.5 voltage ratio that turns into a 2.5 resistance ratio, i.e. R2=20ohm.

Then on the Thevenin voltage V1, you have the same voltage divider but upside down and so

$$V_1\frac{R1}{R1+R2}=1.65\,\mathrm{V}$$

$$V1=1.65\,\mathrm{V}\times\frac{7}{5}=2.31\,\mathrm{V}$$

From now on you should only design R3/R4 divider to have 20ohm and 2.31V Thevenin equivalent.